# Why can't I use a nullable tuple for a nullable generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, tuples, nullable

So I wondered if you could create an extension method that would combine the functionality of `.Where()` and `.Select()` for the special case that it filters out null values of a list and keeps the types consistent with Nullable Reference Types. This means if I got an `string?[]` it would filter out all `null` values and return an `IEnumerable<string>` without nullable strings.

However, when I try to filter out nullable tuples as shown below, I get the compiler error that the non-nullable tuple type was expected.
Why does this solution work for all conventional types yet not for tuples and how can I change my extension method to also work for tuples.

**Extension Method:**

```cs
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectNotNull<TSource, TResult>
(this IEnumerable<TSource> enumerable, Func<TSource, TResult?> selector)
{
    foreach (var item in enumerable)
        if (selector(item) is { } result)
            yield return result;
}
```

**Sample Code that produces the compiler error:**

```cs
(string?, int)[] arr = Array.Empty<(string?, int)>();

static (string, int)? Selector((string?, int) x)
{
    return x.Item1 != null ? x : null;
}

arr.SelectNotNull<(string?, int), (string, int)>(Selector);
```

Comment: `(string?, int)` isn't a nullable Tuple maybe you meant to do `(string?, int)?`

Comment: Note that this doesn't work for all value types, not just tuples.

Comment: @RandRandom You are right, `(string?, int)` is not a nullable Tuple, however the filter Method "Selector" produces the nullable tuple `(string, int)?` which is then produces the compiler error.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, I seem to have made a mistake while verifying if it affected all value types, which is why I thought it would only cause problems for tuples.

Comment: well `TResult?` isn't a nullable type either, you have only told the compiler you are expecting a null value, eg. a reference type `class Foo` could be null, only structs can be declared nullable so for TResult? to be a nullable you would have to limit the TResult to only structs `where TResult : struct` - as it is now you are using c# 8 nullable feature https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references

Comment: @RandRandom I suspected as much. Why is there such a hard cut between nullable structs and nullable reference types that causes this kind of behavior?

Comment: there is no such thing as "nullable reference types" in c# - that's the difference every reference type can be null, you can't declare a nullable reference type, even with c# 8 and the "new" feature the type `string?` isn't `Nullable<string>` it is just "magic" for the compiler to give you warnings that you try to assign a null to something you haven't explizitly declared it could be null, eg. `string str = null;` is totally valid c# code, you don't have to write `string? str = null;` but if you have the c#8 feature enabled you will get a warning with the first

Comment: (cont) ... while structs can actually be nullable see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oab6v.png - the difference between warning/error

Comment: why c# design team decided this, I have no clue, its just the way it is and I roll with it

Comment: maybe you have a chance and EricLippert sees this and gives his thought

Comment: It's quite simple: the differences between reference type and structs comes from the CLI. In CLI there is no concept of a non-nullable reference type (they can always be null), so in C# it had to be just a compiler warning. Whereas valuetypes (as structs are called) themselves cannot be null. Nullable valuetypes are built in, `int?` is really `Nullable<int>` and is defined by the Base Class Library as `Nullable<T> where T : struct`, so the implementation is already there.

Comment: @Charlieface - I believe the question was more, atleast that's how I understood it, and that's what I said I don't know, why wasn't c# written from the ground up to have `Nullable<struct>` and `Nullable<class>` why did they differ in the first place? so why was this `string str = null;` ever valid c# code and not just do it identically to `structs` and you would need to declare it as `Nullable<string> str = null;` or `string? str null;` - so why wasn't `non-nullable reference type` a concept in the CLI ?

Comment: @RandRandom Mainly because it hadn't been thought of. Coders were at the time coming from C++, and wouldn't have been familiar with such a concept. There ar many many other things that should have been thought of but were not, not least proper `IDisposable`, but it is what it is, we can't change it all now.

Comment: @RandRandom This is actually how I thought the annotation `#nullable enable` would work when I first started using it. I thought the compiler would translate `string?` as `Nullable<string>` which is where the confusion came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a constraint, your `TResult?` is interpreted as a reference-type nullability annotation (and you should see a CS8632 warning if reference-type nullability isn't enabled, or a hard error if using earlier C# compiler versions) - and nullability annotations are *very much* just advisory; they don't change any hard behaviours. To get the behaviour you seem to want *with value types*, you can add:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectNotNull<TSource, TResult>
(this IEnumerable<TSource> enumerable, Func<TSource, TResult?> selector)
    where TResult : struct // <== add constraint
```

However, this then won't work with reference types at all.

Comment: I am using C# 9 with nullable reference types enabled. I had hoped that I could write one extension method to handle both nullable value types as well as nullable reference types. This, however, seems not to be possible

Comment: @Blu3Souls indeed; that would be a bigger change to the behaviour than can be achieved by what is just an annotation